# Including SVG contents in Laravel 5 Blade template

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

What is the best way to include the contents of an SVG file (located in the assets folder) in a Laravel 5 blade template?

I don't want to use image/object/embed tags, this should be an inline SVG for reasons of speed.

I know I could use `<?php file_get_contents("file.svg") ?>` but is there a better way specific to Laravel/Blade?

Edit: to clarify, the method should work with *all* SVG files, including the one below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path stroke="red" fill="#00f" d="M10 10h100v100H10z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What is that .svg look like ? Is it a sprites image with different icons ?

Comment: What happens when you do `<?php include("file.svg") ?>` did you see anything render ?

Comment: The SVG is a logo. Should have been file_get_contents() not include(), but it did work (when SVG had no XML version element). I just wanted to find a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Similar to the accepted answer but a bit cleaner (imo).

Use the laravel directive to extend blade, like so (in your App Service Provider, as outlined [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade)):

```
    \Blade::directive('svg', function($arguments) {
        // Funky madness to accept multiple arguments into the directive
        list($path, $class) = array_pad(explode(',', trim($arguments, "() ")), 2, '');
        $path = trim($path, "' ");
        $class = trim($class, "' ");

        // Create the dom document as per the other answers
        $svg = new \DOMDocument();
        $svg->load(public_path($path));
        $svg->documentElement->setAttribute("class", $class);
        $output = $svg->saveXML($svg->documentElement);

        return $output;
    });
```

Then use it in your blade like so:

```
        <div class="Login__image Login__cloud">
            @svg('cloud.svg', 'Cloud')
        </div>
```

Comment: well, it's nice to see how to extend blade. If it is better is a different question though with all the processing and the whole ceremony? all the question marks for the next reader? i would just use `<?= file_get_contents("file.svg") ?>` tbh

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: For Sage (Roots WP theme), I used it like this: ```sage('blade')->compiler()->directive('svg', function ($arguments) {
        list($path, $class) = array_pad(explode(',', trim($arguments, "() ")), 2, '');
        $path = trim($path, "' ");
        $class = trim($class, "' ");
        $svg = new \DOMDocument();
        $svg->load(asset_path($path));
        $svg->documentElement->setAttribute("class", $class);
        $output = $svg->saveXML($svg->documentElement);
        return $output;
    });```

Comment: @Toskan The point of the processing is to remove the XML version element which would invalidate the HTML if included.

Answer (score 31):

This works, that's the simplest way I could think about :

```
{!! file_get_contents('images/icon.svg') !!}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that the XML version element (if it exists in the SVG) gets included in the HTML.

Answer (score 23):

Why not place the svg into a blade template?

```
resources/views/icons/dashboard.blade.php
```

then add in your views using blade syntax?

```
@include('icons.dashboard')
```

Answer (score 7):

## View Composer Method

I ended up using a view composer in a service provider.

In the service provider's `boot()` method:

```php
// Wildcard view composer
view()->composer('*', function($view) {
    // Instantiate new DOMDocument object
    $svg = new DOMDocument();
    // Load SVG file from public folder
    $svg->load(public_path('images/logo.svg'));
    // Add CSS class (you can omit this line)
    $svg->documentElement->setAttribute("class", "logo");
    // Get XML without version element
    $logo = $svg->saveXML($svg->documentElement);
    // Attach data to view
    $view->with('logo', $logo);
});
```

And in my view:

```html
<!-- Echo unescaped SVG content -->
{!! $logo !!}
```

I am using `DOMDocument` as it allows me to remove the XML version element which should not be in the HTML.

The CSS class is not essential but saves me wrapping the logo with another HTML element for styling.

If you only need the logo in a specific Blade partial such as header you could write

```php
view()->composer('header', function($view) {});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25

## Blade Partial Method

This method is not best practice since this sort of code should not really be in a view. However it is very simple and much better than adding PHP code in every single view.

Make a new partial (lets say logo.blade.php) with the following code:

```html
<?php
// Instantiate new DOMDocument object
$svg = new DOMDocument();
// Load SVG file from public folder
$svg->load(public_path('images/logo.svg'));
// Add CSS class (you can omit this line)
$svg->documentElement->setAttribute("class", "logo");
// Echo XML without version element
echo $svg->saveXML($svg->documentElement);
?>
```

You can now use the SVG image in a blade template by including the partial like so:

```html
@include('logo')
```