# How to print barcode generate xml in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I ma laravel app i have genrated borcode through there package and it is created as xml so how to print xml in laravel bleade template.

this is the code

```
$last_inserted_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        $qr_code = \QrCode::size(500)->generate($request->phone_no);
        BdUser::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'cnic' => $request->cnic,
            'phone_no' => $request->phone_no,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => md5($request->password),
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'level_id' => $request->level_id,
            'is_bd_partner' => $request->is_bd_partner,
            'limit' => $request->limit,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'address' => $request->address,
            'qr_code' => $qr_code,
            'unique_code' => $unique_code
        ]);
```

this is the Xml generated code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500"><defs><rect id="r0" width="17" height="17" fill="#000000"/></defs><r
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including SVG contents in Laravel 5 Blade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058556/including-svg-contents-in-laravel-5-blade-template)

Comment: actually it is a barcode xml

Comment: can you check if the generated xml above is correct , i try to preview the svg but i see that is non-correct format

Comment: but it create like that i think the generated xml code is not right

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it as base64 image :

```
$png = base64_encode($qr_code);
```

Return the $png and then show it as picture :

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64," . {{ $png }} . "'>
```